# Will there be some simple CMS functionality in meteor?

Tags: meteor

Will there be some meteor package for filling the (non reactive) website around the webapp itself with content?

Comment: Will there be? (This seems like the sort of things MLs are good for...)

Comment: As meteor is still in alpha state, i asked, if there will be something like that in the future.. whats wrong with that?

Comment: It's not on-topic. I voted to close (for being off-topic) and suggested that the MLs would be a more appropriate location to ask about this sort of thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> http://meteor.com/faq/can-meteor-serve-static-html

### Can Meteor serve static HTML? Does Meteor work with JavaScript disabled on the client? Can Meteor sites be indexed by Google?

Meteor has been carefully designed to support this important use case, but it's not in the current Meteor builds. It will be part of our upcoming Routing release, which will make it easy to build Meteor sites that are aware of the current URL.

Briefly, the way server-side rendering works is that the Meteor app is started on the server and allowed to render the page. Then the session state is serialized (using the same migration technology behind Hot Code Push) and the app is frozen and pushed down to the browser, where it can optionally be restarted if the browser supports JavaScript. Since Meteor templating is based on HTML strings, not DOM manipulation, it's not necessary to run a DOM emulation package on the server.